moving TFS 13 repositiory to Google GIT repository
Need some advise/help on how to move source repository from TFS Version 13 SP5 to Google GIT repository. I have seen many articles but mostly for Azure
My TFS repository has many medium size projects and I think it would be cost effective to use Google GITrepository instead of moving to Azure.
Thanks for your help

What do you mean by 'TFS'? A TFVC collection hosted on a TFS server? Or some git repositories hosted on a TFS server? In both cases, git hosting target service doesn't really matter... (in the 1st case because you migrate locally and push wherever you want)

Do you have an on-premise TFS Server (aka Azure DevOps Server) and you have decided against moving to the cloud version (Azure DevOps Services)? By "TFS 13" do you mean "Team Foundation Server 2013"? Is your repo TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) or git?

Yes . We have TFS 13 on premise and  the repo is TFVC and save in SQLServer . I cannot go directly from TFS 13 to Azure DevOps Server. We have Google cloud platform and I want to use GIT in GCP.  Is it possible to go from TFVC to GCP GIT?

The difficult part is converting a TFVC repo in git one(s). After that moving from local git repos or hosted ones to another hosting service (like Google Cloud) is not that difficult.

Giving an example of the "many articles" you found could help in this discussion...

As you are using the TFVC repo in TFS, you can check this document Migrate from TFVC to Git. Before migrating source code from TFVC to Git, understand the differences between the two and prepare for the migration.

The Git-TFS tool is a two-way bridge between Team Foundation Version Control and Git, and you can use it to perform a migration.

You can check the detailed steps here. The only difference is to replace the remote git repository URL with your Google GIT repository URL.
